# How to run the npm run build, when frontend (ReactJS) and backend (NodeJs,Express) are in two different folders

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My file structure would look something like:

./client

```
 .react
```

./server

```
 .express
```

`.express` and `.react` are just shorthand for all of my files in these folders. So I have separate `node_modules` folders for each of these directories.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it with `npm` itself. It might be handy to create a Makefile in the root, running your required build steps.

[This article](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile) explains how to create a Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

This same happen to me when I worked on the good solution is to make top level on these two workspaces. Just visit the given url [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) you will get the idea how to manage that kind of flow and single top level package.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `npm run build` to build the react app